# How to split a string without space between word and number?

Tags: python

I have a string `40% Apple23% Orange21.2% Bananas` and i need to get an array like: `Apple (40%), Orange (23%), Bananas (21.2%)`. I guess `.split()` not working here. How can i do this?

Comment: You can try this regex `\d+%[ ]\D+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```py
import re

s = "40% Apple23% Orange21.2% Bananas"

out = []
for amount, fruit in re.findall(r"(\d+\.?\d*)\s*%\s*([^\d]+)", s):
    out.append("{} ({}%)".format(fruit, amount))

print(", ".join(out))
```

Prints:

```
Apple (40%), Orange (23%), Bananas (21.2%)
```